# Change text of tree widget node

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've written a piece of code that creates a tree widget:

```
(require 'tree-widget)

(defun my-create-tree-widget ()
  (interactive)
  (with-current-buffer 
    (get-buffer-create "*my-tree-widget*")
    (setq-local my-tree-widget
        (widget-create
         'tree-widget
         :open t
         :tag "one"
         :args
         (list (widget-convert
            'tree-widget
            :tag "two"
            :args (mapcar 
                    (apply-partially #'widget-convert 'item)
                    '("three" "four"))))))
    (switch-to-buffer (current-buffer))))
```

The resulting tree widget looks like this, with the `:tag` arguments becoming the labels of the nodes:

```
[-] one
 `-[+] two
```

Now I want to change the labels from my program, but setting the `:tag` value with `widget-put` doesn't change anything in the buffer.  How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason, the label of a tree widget node is stored as the first element in the `:children` property, so you need to retrieve that value, and change its `:tag` property, not the `:tag` property of the tree widget itself.

After changing the `:tag` property, you need to force the widget to update.  You can do that using `widget-value-set`.  Since you don't actually want to change the value, just assign the same value again; it will still have the same effect of redrawing the widget.

For example, to update the top-level node:

```
(defun my-change-tree-widget-first-level ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((node (car (widget-get my-tree-widget :children))))
    (widget-put node :tag (format-time-string "%T"))
    ;; Redraw
    (widget-value-set node (widget-value node))))
```

This results in:

```
[-] 12:39:19
 `-[+] two
```

To update a child node, just dig down using the `:children` property, keeping in mind that the first "child" element is not strictly speaking a child:

```
(defun my-change-tree-widget-second-level ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((second-level (cadr (widget-get my-tree-widget :children))))
    (unless (tree-widget-p second-level)
      (error "This is not the tree widget"))
    (let ((node (car (widget-get second-level :children))))
      (widget-put node :tag (format-time-string "%T"))
      ;; Redraw
      (widget-value-set node (widget-value node)))))
```

With this final result:

```
[-] 12:39:19
 `-[+] 12:40:41
```

Comment: This is not correct.  When you open and close the `two` button, the label `two` will stand out again.